# Sorting data in an ascending order in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a very long dataset which I wanted to sort in an ascending order. I am getting a little confused looking at the output because the indexes does not run from 0 to n, after sorting. my code looks like this:

```
import pandas
import numpy

def imputation(filename):


    ref = pandas.read_csv(filename, sep= ',', names = ['data'])

    sort_values = ref.sort_values(['data'], ascending=True)
    q =sort_values.head(10)
    return q

print imputation("file_location")
```

the output looks the following:

```
                                      data
0     0.000000e+0 3.736717e-1 -8.896232e-2
1000  1.000000e-1 3.870175e-1 -8.870570e-2
100   1.000000e-2 3.749366e-1 -8.894183e-2
10    1.000000e-3 3.737975e-1 -8.896031e-2
1     1.000000e-4 3.736843e-1 -8.896212e-2
1001  1.001000e-1 3.870317e-1 -8.870538e-2
1002  1.002000e-1 3.870459e-1 -8.870506e-2
1003  1.003000e-1 3.870601e-1 -8.870474e-2
1004  1.004000e-1 3.870742e-1 -8.870442e-2
1005  1.005000e-1 3.870884e-1 -8.870410e-2
```

I don't know if I am doing something wrong in the code, but should not I expect the index going from 0 to n in an ascending order too? Also my data is few thousand rows, so it got split into 3 separate columns apparently. so in this output, do I start reading data from the rightmost column? your explanation is most appreciated.

Comment: Apparently comma is  _not_ the separator of your CSV file. What you see is a dataframe (probably a series) that has only one column. The separators have not been parsed. You may want to check `ref.shape`.

Comment: HI, yes, `ref.shape' returns `(10000, 1)', so it has only one column and 10000 rows, in cases like this, what is the best way to sort lines?

Comment: Sort _how_? By what criterion?

Comment: 1. What is your csv looking like? 2. How do you want to sort?

Comment: sort from lowest to highest values

Answer (score 1):

First, it is better to read csv with proper seperator (looks like tab \t)
, and then sort by index.

yet, if you want to proceed from your (10000,1) shaped dataframe, this may works.

```
# extract your index as an integer from "data" column
# if not tab, remove '\t'
ref['index'] = ref['data'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('\t')[0]))
ref.sort_values(by='index')
```